# java - do I have to overwrite all versions of overloaded function in inheriting class?

Tags: java

Because I need a cancelable OutputStreamWriter, id did the following

```
public class CancelableStreamWriter extends OutputStreamWriter {

    public CancelableStreamWriter(OutputStream out, String charsetName) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        super(out, charsetName);
        //stuff
    }

    public CancelableStreamWriter(OutputStream out) {
        super(out);
        //stuff
    }

    public CancelableStreamWriter(OutputStream out, Charset cs) {
        super(out, cs);
        //stuff
    }

    public CancelableStreamWriter(OutputStream out, CharsetEncoder enc) {
        super(out, enc);
        //stuff
    }

    public void write(int c) throws IOException {
        if (myCancelCondition) {
            // cancel stuff
        }
        super.write(c);
    }

    public void write(char cbuf[], int off, int len) throws IOException {
        if (myCancelCondition) {
            // cancel stuff
        }
        super.write(cbuf, off, len);
    }

    public void write(String str, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        if (myCancelCondition) {
            // cancel stuff
        }
        super.write(str, off, len);
    }
}
```

I wonder, if I really have to overwrite all overloaded versions of the write function. Or is there something possible like:

```
    public void write(WHATEVERARGS) throws IOException {
        if (myCancelCondition) {
            // cancel stuff
        }
        super.write(WHATEVERARGS);
    }
```

Same with constrcutors.

Maybe this is not the most elegant approach at all, but I can't use a wrapper object for example, since the owning class is typed to OutputStreamWriter and I can't change that.

Comment: You can't inherit or override constructors. You do have to override all methods you want to override; sadly there's no magic panacea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Keep your approach.

Unfortunately, it is not possible and there is no shortcut for overriding all methods (or "overriding" all constructors). Java methods and constructors must have fixed parameters. This is because of language design.

Fortunately, most IDEs support generating such code in a few clicks. You just have to select that you want to override all methods and constructors (and then add your custom functionality).

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how internal logic is organized and what are public entry points.

For example, if youd super class would have some sort of set of overloaded methods, lets say `A(X)` `A(X,Y)` etc. and implementation of those methods would do some transformation only to call something like `protected internalA(X,Y,Z...)` than obviously overriding `internalA` will do the trick as all other paths will go trough that method. If all of them are doing different stuff, then you are out of luck and probably you have to override all possible entry points.

Another "hack" would be to use proxy that will intercept calls to an interface (if it is interface not class) and decide what to do with such call on runtime, but it might be overkill in your case. 
It seems that you suggest that you want to do exaclty the same thing - intercept call, process arguments, pass call trough. Thic can be done with proxy.

Since `OutputStreamWriter` internally does not delegate to single internal method, you should overload all of them, or accept the risk that "unpached" method will be used by someone.

Answer (score 1):

With looking into the sources or testing you might find out what does not need to be be overriden. Better seems to use a [**`FilterWriter`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/?java/io/Writer.html) as base class, as that is its purpose.

Whether to combine your own Writer functionality with conversion from a binary OutputStream is the question: there are some overloaded constructors you would need to keep.

```
public class CancelableStreamWriter extends FilterWriter {

    public CancelableStreamWriter(OutputStream out, String charsetName)
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        super(new OutputStreamWriter(out, charsetName));
        //stuff
    }
```

Comment: Ok, I could use FilterWriter, but that does not solve my problem in any way, because I have to override the very same functions / function-variants.

Comment: Besides 1 constructor there is 1 flush and 3 write methods. Javadoc: "Subclasses of FilterWriter should override _some_ of these methods ..." Unfortunately there is no guarantee of root low-level methods - you are right. If the number of constructors is too large for future child classes, then have static builder methods as in Files.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I would spare some of the constructors.